# Php exec encoding

Tags: php, debian, command-line-interface

When I execute from console this command "sendsms XXXXXXXXX 'śćźłóśadad'" everything is OK. But when I execute it in php with exec("sendsms XXXXXXXXX 'śćźłóśadad'"); the body of msg is without polish letters. Debian console is in UTF-8, php file is in UTF-8. When I execute this php file from cli everything is OK but the problem is when I run it from browser (the same file). Why ? How to fix it ?

Comment: What is "without polish letters"? Do they come out as mojibake, or are they completely ignored?

Comment: cosśźć => cos (cut the string)

Comment: _but the problem is when I run it from browser_ - is "cosśźć" user input? if so, sounds like your html page is missing a UTF-8 metatag, and the string your script receives is not what you think.

Comment: No, input is in UTF but I tried run this without input just exec("sendsms 888888888 cosśźćłó");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run your script via the CLI interface, the subprocess inherits its parent's environment, which contains the variable `LANG`, used to pass the encoding of the bytes to the underlying C runtime.

Likely when you execute your program via mod_php, `LANG` is not set. So you may succeed by configuring it yourself:

```
<?php
putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');
exec("sendsms 888888888 cosśźćłó");
```